# SpringBoot 3 using semicolon in JPA query

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, java-17, spring-boot-3

I have a JPA query in Spring Boot 3 that search for a text with semicolon. The query is like this:

```
Query(value=".... LIKE CONCAT(?, '%;') ...")
```

It ends up generating the following query

```
LIKE CONCAT(?, '% limit ?;')
```

I tried different approaches to use ESCAPE the key word or adding \\ but all didn't success. The same code was working earlier in Spring Boot 2.7

I don't know what problem there are after the upgrade!
Any ideas?

**Update**
This normal query works fine with the List

```
@Query(value = "SELECT u.* FROM  user u WHERE u.userId LIKE CONCAT(?1, '%;') OR u.userId IN ?2)", nativeQuery = true)
List<UserEntity> search(String search, List<String> userIds);
```

If we replace the List with pagination, then it fails

```
@Query(value = "SELECT u.* FROM  user u WHERE u.userId LIKE CONCAT(?1, '%;') OR u.userId IN ?2)", nativeQuery = true)
Page<UserEntity> search(String search, List<String> userIds, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Could you post all your query? Have you insert nativeQuery = true?

Comment: @fforfabio I have added the simplified query without joins

Comment: I have tried a query with concat and semicolon, with Spring Boot 3.1.4, and it works fine as I expected. I have escape the ; with this instruction `LIKE CONCAT(?1, '%' , ';')`.    So, I have two questions: 1) Can you explain exactly your problem? Is the query retrieving the wrong data or something else?  2) Which version of Spring Boot have you have installed?

Comment: Thanks @fforfabio for your trail, yes it works for normal quires, I got to know the real issue now, it's related to the pagination, as per my understanding for some reasons the pagable object tries to look for the semicolon to add the limit before it directly, that's why I see the limit before the semicolon LIKE CONCAT(?1, ' limit ?;') and breaks the code. I think it's a bug inside Spring data. the point I'm still confused why it worked earlier in older versions

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the semicolon issue with pagination, I did the below work-around by replacing pagination using Page with List and create my own custom pagination logic with additional counter query

```
@Query(value = "SELECT u.* FROM  user u WHERE u.userId LIKE CONCAT(?1, ';%') OR u.userId IN ?2) limit ?3, ?4", nativeQuery = true)
List<UserEntity> search(String search, List<String> userIds, int page, int size);

@Query(value = "SELECT count(u.userId) FROM  user u WHERE u.userId LIKE CONCAT(?1, ';%') OR u.userId IN ?2)", nativeQuery = true)
Integer searchCount(String search, List<String> userIds);

Integer total = userDao.searchCount(search , userIds);
List list = userDao.search(search, userIds , page * size, size);
Page<UserEntity> = new PageImpl(list, PageRequest.of(page, size), total);
```